# Javascript Swipeable stacked cards with Swiper slider

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, swiper.js

I am trying to achieve something like this

[image]

Where the cards can be flicked up or down to move forward or backward in slider?

I tried this but I am lost how to make it work.

Issues I am facing
1. Unable to achieve the desired css stack effect
2. While scrolling, instead of showing the next slide in the list, all the slides just scroll up.

This is what I have tried so far - https://codepen.io/arjunmenon/pen/pOdmXB

CSS

```
.swiper-slide {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  outline: 1px solid transparent;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform-origin: 50% 60%;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  transform: scale(.8);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  z-index: -1;
}

.swiper-slide:first-child {
  -webkit-transform: scale(.7);
  transform: scale(1);
}

.swiper-slide:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform: scale(.8);
  transform: scale(.7);
}

.swiper-slide:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: scale(.9);
  transform: scale(.8);
}
.swiper-slide-active {
  z-index: 999;
  height: 80vh !important;
  transform: scale(1);
}
.swiper-slide-next {
  z-index: 100;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your providing codepen.io.

Comment: is it solved yet ?

Comment: With Swiper, no it isn't. The library author at this point probably is not looking to support this feature, but cards based layouts is something which gives good UX.